Need help pulling a column of dates from one worksheet to another and its corresponding party column with excel formulas
i'm working with about 50,000 rows of data in my spreadsheet.  Luckily my task is to only pull the dates associated with a say team A from the year 2020.  I started by sorting my data but i was told i have to use formulas.  There is only about 25 dates where team A was in 2020.  I was told i could use an If function but i am dealing with dates so i tried this and i get the numbers i need, however is it possible to nest this filter and sequence function or is it possible to use this sort function, open to all functions but got furtherst on these.
the dates in the column range from 1900-2020 so im using a filter function to return the dates and trying to only get those 25 from 2020 in 02/09/2020 format. So my spreadsheet shoould only pull in those 25 rows in that column into the next sheet with their corresponding team whether its team a, b,c,d doesnt matter as long as it will pull in the correct dates in order from earliest to latest in 2020 it should show the columns
corresponding team
=FILTER(result!C:C,result!K:K=result!K2,"") =DATE(2020,"1",SEQUENCE(365))

is this possible to wrap^^ keeps showing result as false
or
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(TEXT(result!C:C[DATE],("YYYY-MM"),(result!C:C=K2)*(result!L:L),"")))

or an if statement im not picky

I am not able to understand what you are doing. You should try this: =FILTER(result!C:C,(YEAR(result!C:C)=2020)*(result!K:K=K2),"") if you aware that the FILTER() will return duplicates then wrap around UNIQUE() and SORT() to get a sorted list. =SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(result!C:C,(YEAR(result!C:C)=2020)*(result!K:K=K2),""))) let me know. Also if possible try avoid using the whole rows, that is I am asking you to use Structured References instead of iterating blank rows.

so i have a column im trying to print or display in another sheet in excel.  the issue is im working with big data so theres 50,000 rows.  however, there is only 25 dates in the column of 50,000 with the date range of 1/1/2020 to 12/31/2020. I am trying to return these 25 dates between 1/1/2020- 12/31/2020 for example column a is my formula and it should return 2/01/2020 instead of 05/17/1945.

Have you tried the formula yet? And regarding the date formatting you can do it from the home tab under number grouping select custom to format as you like

it did not work. i have to make my data dynamic hence formula.  all i want to do is use a formula to pull the 25 dates and its corresponding team name into 2 columns to basically serve as a formula to lookup criteria between dates and which team was there on each date

Post some sample data using Markdown_Table. I just followed your explanation, you have posted not sure which column represents what, so I assumed from the formula of yours Column K is for team while Column C is for dates. Also I don't see how that formula will not work, as an example i have tried on my end. it does work. Could you show a screenshot how it is not working. and ofcourse you should post some sample data using markdown

or like as a directory if you wanted to know what dates something was open imusing this dynamic formula so you could search through all the dates based on the formula mine just happens to be 2020 but for sake of argument say i wanted to see the data from 2022. its just to make it easier for the person trying to view the data instead of going through 50k rows

Not edited the post yet with relevant information to show us.

As mentioned, giving the information requested would be step one in helping.  Would you be allowed to use PowerQuery instead of a formula?

You should be able to accomplish your task using simply a FILTER formula.
I used the formula below, filtering by Team and by the Year in the table. In the "Include" section of the filter formula you can do ( [condition1] ) * ( [condition2] ) in order to apply multiple conditions to filter by, within these conditions you can other formulas such as Year if you want to filter by year, or you can bound them more targeted using beginning and end dates as well as {<,>,<=,>=,=} operators.
=FILTER($A$2:$B$20,($A$2:$A$20=$E$3)*(YEAR($B$2:$B$20)=YEAR($E$2)))
You can further sort and eliminate duplicates, for example you see I have two rows here for the 7/3/2020, and wrapping this whole formula into a UNIQUE( filter... ) allows you to remove these instance if you want them gone, like so:
=UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$B$20,($A$2:$A$20=$E$3)*(YEAR($B$2:$B$20)=YEAR($E$2))))

